# Can a Test of Difference in Two Proportions be used to compare two different types of probabilities from a single population?

Tags: hypothesis-testing

I get that the test of difference in two proportions are usually for studying comparing a single type of proportion between two different populations.
But if I am interested in comparing two different types of probabilities from a single population, can I still apply the test of difference in two proportions to these two type of probabilities?
For example, if for a given population of students, if the proportion of the students that scores 70% or greater on a test A is $P_A$, and if the proportion of the students that scores 70% or greater on a test B is $P_B$, can I conduct the regular test of difference in two proportions to compare $P_A$ and $P_B$?

Comment: This looks like paired data. Do you have the individual results?